# AngularJS acces controllers $scope inside state onEnter function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have a state inside my  angular .config $stateProvider and I want the onEnter method gain access to the controllers $scope of the state.

My state is declared like this:

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
  .state('panda1', {
    url: '/panda/',
    templateUrl: 'templates/panda.html',
    controller: 'pandaCtrl',
    onEnter: onEnterPanda
  })
  .state(...) //bunch of other states
  .state(...)
}
```

The controller looks something like this:

```
.controller('panda1IntroCtrl',function($scope) {
   $scope.name = "pandaboy1";
})
```

And I hope the onEnterPanda function to somehow look like this

```
function onEnterPanda() {
  var scope = this.getController().get$Scope(); //would be nice
  console.log(scope.name); //pandaboy1
  scope.name = 'pandaboy2';
  console.log(scope.name); //pandaboy2
}
```

I couldn't find any reference to the $scope inside the this object in the onEnterPanda function.

I also know the $scop might be accecibly with something like:

```
angular.element(document.getElementById('yourElementId')).scope();
```

But that doesn't feel like the right answer.

Comment: I think that you are not using the controller scope correctly. It seems that what you really want is to create a service, - that is a singleton object accessible by other controllers and services,- and resolve the service in your state definition.

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear what exactly you are trying to do. But, if I understood it correctly, you want to alter controller setup based on some conditions. Easiest way is to use some service that will provide possibility for getting/setting such conditions.

```
  state('home', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/main.html',
        controller:'panda1IntroCtrl',
        ....
        },
        resolve:{
            info:'infoSvc',
            loadProfile:function(info){
                return info.setMessage("name 2");
            }
        }
    }
```

and then in you mainViewCtl you can do

```
.controller('panda1IntroCtrl',[ '$scope','infoSvc', function($scope, info) {
  $scope.name = info.getMessage();
})
```

Comment: My post was simplyfied for readability reasons, If I can get value from the service when the user enters the page/view, I will accept it.

Comment: Controller is re-created every time you switch to the state. so - yes, you don't even need the resolve block if all you want is to read a value from outside. Resolve block allows you to change service value, if needed, just before you create the controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can place a method within the HTML **ng-init** attribute. This function will be called when you enter the view.

eg

```
<ion-content ng-controller="pandaCtrl" ng-init="PandaSayHi()">...</ion-content>
```